# asyncio Queue - item insertion using regular generator - confusing behaviour, unexpected values

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, python-asyncio

*(with Python 3.8.1)*

I'm adding items to an [asyncio queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) using output from a regular generator function (`job_gen_generator()` below).

Workers pulling items out of the queue receive values that differ from the values (I expect to be) added to the queue using the output of said generator.

Full demo code:

```
import asyncio


def job_gen_generator():
    # incrementally generates trivial "jobs" data in a dict
    job = 1
    job_dict = {
        'job_number': job,
    }
    while True:
        yield job_dict
        job_dict['job_number'] += 1

job_gen = job_gen_generator()


async def worker(instance, q):
    # workers get jobs from the queue
    while True:
        count, job = await q.get()
        print(f'Worker {instance} got queue item: {count} with data of...{job}')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        q.task_done()


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    for count in range(10):
        job = next(job_gen)
        print(f'Adding queue item: {count} with data of... {job}')
        queue.put_nowait((count, job))  # <- Issue here


    # The rest of the code is necessary boilerplate 
    worker_tasks = []
    for instance in range(2):
        task = asyncio.create_task(worker(instance, queue))
        worker_tasks.append(task)

    await queue.join()
    for task in worker_tasks:
        task.cancel()
    await asyncio.gather(*worker_tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Actual output:

```
Adding queue item: 0 with data of... {'job_number': 0}
Adding queue item: 1 with data of... {'job_number': 1}
Adding queue item: 2 with data of... {'job_number': 2}
Adding queue item: 3 with data of... {'job_number': 3}
...etc
Worker 0 got queue item: 0 with data of...{'job_number': 9} # all items are 9, the last output from the generator
Worker 1 got queue item: 1 with data of...{'job_number': 9}
Worker 0 got queue item: 2 with data of...{'job_number': 9}
Worker 1 got queue item: 3 with data of...{'job_number': 9}
...etc
```

Expected output:

```
Adding queue item: 0 with data of... {'job_number': 0}
Adding queue item: 1 with data of... {'job_number': 1}
Adding queue item: 2 with data of... {'job_number': 2}
Adding queue item: 3 with data of... {'job_number': 3}
...etc
Worker 0 got queue item: 0 with data of...{'job_number': 0}
Worker 1 got queue item: 1 with data of...{'job_number': 1}
Worker 0 got queue item: 2 with data of...{'job_number': 2}
Worker 1 got queue item: 3 with data of...{'job_number': 3}
...etc
```

### Question

I don't understand why this behaves this way?

- I understand queue.put_nowait() to be a synchronous function, therefore it should complete before the next loop of the `for` statement begins?
- But it looks like the for loop runs till completion (overwriting the variable capturing the output of the generator), *then* commits all items to the queue but I can't reason why this is the execution flow.

Notes:
I can fix this by wrapping `job` in a `dict()` i.e. `queue.put_nowait((count, dict(job)))` but I don't understand why this helps, all I'm doing is casting a dict to a dict.

Comment: That's just your generator being broken. You're yielding the same dict object every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, you are just yielding the same dict object every time.

```
def job_gen_generator():
    # incrementally generates trivial "jobs" data in a dict
    job = 1
    job_dict = {
        'job_number': job,
    }
    while True:
        yield job_dict
        job_dict['job_number'] += 1
```

It is a loop, every time you call `next`, you get the same object `job_dict`. While in your case, you need different ones right?

```
def job_gen_generator():
    # incrementally generates trivial "jobs" data in a dict
    job = 1
    while True:
        yield {
            'job_number': job,
        }
        job += 1
```